# Hadoop virtual machine: can't connect

Tags: hadoop, vmware

I've downloaded and extracted the Hadoop virtual machine from http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2010/10/yahoo-cloud-virtual-machine-appliance/.  I've started this up in VMWare Player on Windows 7, and logged in.

However, I can't then connect to the IP address shown for the VM through SSH, nor can I ping it.  What could be wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason to Y! VM? I am not sure, if Y! is maintaining it or not. Cloudera CDH [1] is updated on a regular basis and contains more frameworks compared to the Y! VM.

  [1]: https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Downloads

Comment: No particular reason - was just the first one I found.  Will try Cloudera.  Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2011/12/getting-started-with-hadoop-is-easy.html) for instructions on installing CDH using VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to power off the VM, go to the VM settings, and select Network Adapter->Bridged.

Answer (score 0):

what errors are you seeing?
if it is related to 64bit settings (commonly happens when you run it on vmware player), you need to enable it in your BIOS settings and reboot the VM.